# Extract elements from xml file and transform it into another form by using Python

Tags: python, xml

I would like to extract elements from xmi file by using Python, and output the element to a new file in the order I want. For example, I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns="SimpleClass">
  <Class name="AcademicInstitution" is_persistent="false">
    <attrs name="name" is_primary="true" type="/11"/>
  </Class>
```

I would like to transform it into:

```
Class (AcademicInstitution).
Class (false).
```

I have tried to use Python ElementTree, but if I use `node.attrib.get()`, I have to write the code like `node.attrib.get('name')` and  `node.attrib.get('is_persistent')`, and get the result `AcademicInstitution`  and `false`.

But how can I get these results directly without input 'name' and 'is_persistent' in the get()?
And how can I get the 'Class' String from xml file???
Thanks!

Comment: _But how can I get these results directly without input 'name' and 'is_persistent' in the get()?_ What do you mean? It isn't clear what you're trying to do. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], and provide a [mcve].

Comment: _But how can I get these results directly_ I don't understand what you're asking.  The code doesn't magically know that you want the `name` attribute; you have to ask for it _somehow_.  What's wrong with using `node.attrib.get('name')`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `attrib` property of the element is a dictionary of all attributes.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree 

tree = ElementTree.parse('sample.xml')

for el in tree.getiterator():
    _, _, tag = el.tag.rpartition('}')
    for att in el.attrib:
        print(f"{tag} ({el.attrib.get(att)})")
```

Yields the following from your sample (which needs a closing `</xmi:XMI>` to be valid):

```
XMI (2.0)
Class (AcademicInstitution)
Class (false)
attrs (name)
attrs (true)
attrs (/11)
```